# I have created a shiny app to display the plot of stock price of a chosen Company.How do I displaythe prices in a tabular form aswell?

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a shiny app to display the plot of stock price of a chosen Company.I want to displaythe prices in a tabular form aswell,which i am unable to do.On trying an error message states  `cannot coerce class ‘c("reactiveExpr", "reactive")’ to a data.frame`.
The code is as follows:

```
# Load packages ----
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)
```

#edited the code.this can be run directly

```
# User interface ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("stockVis"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Select a stock to examine.

        Information will be collected from Yahoo finance."),
      textInput("symb", "Symbol", "SPY"),

      dateRangeInput("dates",
                     "Date range",
                     start = "2013-01-01",
                     end = as.character(Sys.Date())),

      br(),
      br(),

      checkboxInput("log", "Plot y axis on log scale",
                    value = FALSE)

      #checkboxInput("adjust",
                    #"Adjust prices for inflation", value = FALSE)
    ),

    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"), tableOutput("view")))
  )


# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

  dataInput <- reactive({
     getSymbols(input$symb, src = "yahoo",
               from = input$dates[1],
               to = input$dates[2],
               auto.assign = FALSE)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    chartSeries(dataInput(), theme = chartTheme("white"),
                type = "line", log.scale = input$log, TA = NULL)
  })

  output$view <- renderTable({(dataInput )
  }, include.rownames = TRUE)

}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Gourab, welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, we cannot run your code, since the `source("helpers.R")` isn't working for we don't have that file. Could you include the relevant parts of that file in your code snippet, so that one could copy-paste your code in R and immediately run it? Based on the error you see, I guess you need to call `dataInupt` with brackets: `output$view <- renderTable({dataInput()}, include.rownames = TRUE)`.

Comment: The piece of code('helpers.r:) is not needed.I hav eremoved it and now it can be copied and run in R.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says its a `reactive` function so you have to use it as such: `dataInput()` and not `dataInput`

`output$view <- renderTable({
        dataInput() 
    }, include.rownames = TRUE)`